# Упорядочить матрицу по возрастанию значений в строках по столбцам

Tags: c, сортировка, матрицы

```
#include <stdio.h> #include <conio.h> int main() {
  int i, j;
  int m, n;
  int x, y;
  printf("\nEnter number of rows matrix A \n");//Введите количество строк матрицы А column
 scanf("%d", &m);
 printf("\nEnter number of columns matrix A \n");//Введите количество столбцов матрицы А
 scanf("%d", &n);
 float A[m][n];
 printf("\nEnter matrix A %d x %d elements \n",m,n);//Bведите матрицу A
 for (i=0;i<m; i++) {
    printf("\nElements of %d row: \n",i+1);//Элементы %d-й строки
 for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
      printf("Elem A [%d][%d]", i+1, j+1);
      scanf("%f", &A[i][j]);
    }
  }
 printf("\nMatrix A: \n");//Матрица А
 for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
      printf("%f\t",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  for(y=0; y<m; y++) {
    for (i=0; i<(m-1); i++) {
      if(A[i][0]>A[i+1][0]) {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
          x=A[i][j];
          A[i][j]=A[i+1][j];
          A[i+1][j]=x;
        }
      }
    }
  }
 printf("\n");
 printf("\nSorted matrix A: \n");//Сортированная матрица
 for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
      printf("%f\t",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы упорядочить матрицу по возрастанию значений в строках по столбцам. Если в столбце нашлись совпадающие значения, то переходить на следующий столбец и упорядочивать по нему, и т.д
Например, если исходное

```
1 7 3 4

1 2 4 3

1 2 1 4
```

то должно получиться

```
1 2 1 4

1 2 4 3

1 7 3 4
```

Перерыла много подобных тем, там везде однотипные сортировки пузырьком, как и у меня.

Но проблема в том, что если матрица, например, 5 х 5 и у нее совпадают все числа в первом,втором и третьем столбце, то по четвертому и пятому уже не сортирует. Проверила и на матрице проще и меньше, и оказалось, что оно сортирует только по первому столбику. Как можно изменить этот код так, чтобы сортировка строк проверялась на совпадающие и происходила по всем столбцам

Comment: надо отсортировать матрицу по первому столбцу, потом по второму отсортировать подмножества в которых 1 столбец одинаковый, потом по третьему столбцу подмножества в которых 2 одинаковый и так далее до конца.

Comment: после сортировки очередного столбца у вас одинаковые числа лягут подряд. Берете первое число в столбце и бежите вниз пока не встретите другое число, так определяете границы подмножеств и сортируете их, повторяете процедуру для 2 столбца и так до последнего столбца...

Comment: @AndreyGolikov не думаю что надо использовать блочные сортировки а-ля черпак там где от них нет большой пользы. Особенно новичку, который там может наделать много ошибок.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, нужно правильно написать компаратор. Далее можно использовать стандартную функцию (метка `c` а `c++` поэтому именно так).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int N = 3;
const int M = 4;

int a[N][M] = { {1,7,3,4},{1,2,4,3}, {1,2,1,4} }; 

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    const int *aa = (const int *)a;
    const int *bb = (const int *)b;
    for (int i=0;i<M;i++)
        if (aa[i] != bb[i])
            return aa[i] - bb[i];
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    qsort(a, N, sizeof(int)*M,cmp);
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<M;j++)
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вы же сравнивали только по первому элементу `if(A[i][0]>A[i+1][0])` собственно как написали, так она и работала.

Если отрицательных чисел *точно* не будет (тип данных `unsigned`) то можно писать так:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return memcmp(a,b,sizeof(int)*M);
}
```